# Changing the value of one attribute in a Ruby collection

Tags: ruby, collections

Say for example I've got a collection like this:

```
[{"name" => "Ganesh", "magic_number" => 7}, {"name" => "Comrade", "magic_number" => 2}...]
```

How can I change the value of ALL the magic_numbers in the collection to be the same value (e.g. 8)?

I'm sure it's using something like map or collect but I can't seem to do it at the moment and return me the whole collection with the changes, just one or the other...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `.each`:

```
a = [{"name" => "Ganesh", "magic_number" => 7}, {"name" => "Comrade", "magic_number" => 2} ]
a.each { |x| x['magic_number'] = 8 }
# a is now [{"magic_number"=>8, "name"=>"Ganesh"}, {"magic_number"=>8, "name"=>"Comrade"}]
```

The argument to the block is a reference to the original elements so you can change them as desired. Note that this changes `a` in-place which I think is what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
x = [{"name" => "Ganesh", "magic_number" => 7}, {"name" => "Comrade", "magic_number" => 2}]
x.map{|i| i["magic_number"] = 0; i }

=> [{"magic_number"=>0, "name"=>"Ganesh"}, {"magic_number"=>0, "name"=>"Comrade"}]
```

Comment: That returns a new array of hashes with the values changed. The OP wanted them changed in place.

Comment: @the Tin Man: They are changed in place, the `.map` block is operating on references to values in the `x` array.